# Security guideline to store highly confidential data on DBMS

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database, oracle

Recently I've a project that need to use highly confidential data (such as salary). I'm now studying which Database system (Oracle/MSSQL/MySQL) can suite project's security requirements. The security requirements:

1. Encrypt sensitive data
2. Monitor user's actions
3. Limit access to data rows and columns
4. Limit privileges
5. Network encryption

If possible even DBA also won't be able to view those highly confidential data.

Comment: I guess the project's not in Sweden then!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cannot comment for other databases but in Oracle you can implement the following features to meet your security requirements.

**Transparent Data Encryption**

Transparent Data Encryption (TDE) stops would-be attackers from bypassing the database and reading sensitive information from storage by enforcing data-at-rest encryption in the database layer.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/options/advanced-security/index-099011.html

**Oracle Virtual Private Database**

Oracle Virtual Private Database (VPD) enables you to create security policies to control database access at the row and column level.

https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/DBSEG/vpd.htm#DBSEG80081

**Oracle Database Vault**

Oracle Database Vault restricts access to specific areas in an Oracle database from any user, including users who have administrative access. For example, you can restrict administrative access to employee salaries, customer medical records, or other sensitive information.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b31222/dvintro.htm

*Using the Oracle Database Vault feature it is possible to restrict DBAs from accessing highly confidential data.*

**Privileges and Roles**

Permitting only certain users to access, process, or alter data.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/network.111/b28531/authorization.htm#BABCHEJB

**Database Auditing**

Monitoring and recording of selected user database actions.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/network.102/b14266/auditing.htm#CHDJBDHJ

Further, you can refer to the database security guide for details.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/network.102/b14266/toc.htm

Comment: Thanks for your comments